# Can't edit the glade file in visual ruby

Tags: ruby

I've just installed visual ruby. When I create a new project called coinflip and try to edit the glade file the following message:

```
The following command couldn't run
glade C:/Users/Asd/visualruby/coinflip/src/glade/MyClass.glade
Check the path in Tools > Settings
In MS Windows you may need to add the 'start' command i.e. 'start glade'
```

When I opened the settings and changed the glade command line to 'start glade', the following window appeared:

```
Windows cannot find 'glade'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and 
then try again.
```

any help ?

Comment: Whatever glade is, you probably need to install that as well.

Comment: It's already installed. I installed it as well as the gtk gem related to it.